# Как изменить язык интернет страницы с помощью Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Имеется интернет страница на которой есть выбор языка (английский, русский и т.д.).
Как задать чтобы браузер автоматически открывал страницу на английском с помощью Selenium?

Comment: Чтобы открывал автоматически уже нужную локаль - нужно знать как он Вас определяет, скорее всего по ИП - берет страну, и показывает нужный язык. Но можно через исходный код страницы найти селектор по которому переключатель срабатывает, или ссылку - и эту ссылку поставить на выполнение в Selenium